# is it possible to add a real domain in local laptop virtualbox centos 7 or ubuntu 18.04 os?

Tags: dns, virtualbox, centos7, ubuntu-18.04

I have a real domain from godday.com, now I am trying to add this domain to my laptop virtualbox centos or ubuntu operating system. So is it really possible if possible then i will install cpanel and whm in my virtualbox centos7 for learning purpose. Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "add this domain to ... centos or ubuntu"? Do you want to resolve the domain to the local IP address of the virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can host your domain name from your local machine, for that your machine should have either public static IP address assigned or you need to use some dynamic dns services eg. no-ip.com